# Does a Filipina need a visa to change planes in South Korea?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, transit, paperwork, south-korea

My wife has a Philippines passport and a green card and a dependent military ID card from the US. We have a flight that lands in South Korea (we have to claim our bags and recheck them on a different flight the same day); the flights are not connecting and are on two different reservations. We are not leaving the airport. Does she need a visa?

Answer (score 3):

If collecting baggage, you **will** be "leaving the airport", meaning you'll cross the border.

As stated in Timatic, the database used by airlines:

> Visa required, **except** for Nationals of Philippines with a
>   [Green card] if holding confirmed onward tickets on flights departing within
>   30 days; when
>
> -arriving from USA, departing to a third country (e.g.
>   USA-ICN-PVG); **or**
>
> -arriving from a third country, departing to USA (e.g.
>   PVG-ICN-USA); **or**
>
> -arriving from a third country after having transited that
>   country for a maximum stay of 3 days, departing to USA (e.g.
>   PVG-SGN-ICN-USA); **or**
>
> -arriving from a third country, traveling to another country
>   and staying there for a maximum stay of 3 days, then departing
>   to USA (e.g. PVG-ICN-SGN-USA).

So if any of these conditions apply to your wife, she does **not** need a visa.